# Error: This key is already associated with an element of this collection in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code where I am comparing three column values from two different sheets and fetching the value of the fourth column based on the match. While using below code getting the following error:

> This key is already associated with an element of this collection.

```vb
Sub UpdateW2()
    Dim Dic, Dic1 As Object, key As Variant, oCell, oCell2 As Range, i&, i1&
    Dim w1, w2 As Worksheet

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set w1 = Workbooks("Request_Raising_Automation.xlsm").Sheets("RawData")
    Set w2 = Workbooks("Request_Raising_Automation.xlsm").Sheets("BRE")

    i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("B2:D" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 1).Value & oCell.Offset(,2).Value

            i1 = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

            For Each oCell2 In w2.Range("B2:E" & i1)
                Dic1.Add oCell2.Value, oCell2.Offset(, 2).Value & oCell2.Offset(, 3).Value

            If oCell = oCell2 Then
                oCell.Offset(, 3).Value = oCell2.Offset(, 1).Value

 End If
               Next
            End If
         Next

End Sub
```

I want output where i will match 3 columns of two different worksheets and fetch the fourth column value based on the match but this is not working and throwing error.

Comment: On which line do you have the error?

Comment: Line number 14:  Dic1.Add oCell2.Value, oCell2.Offset(, 2).Value & oCell2.Offset(, 3).Value

Comment: You need another check, like this line: ```If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then```

Comment: @LaxeshDave I suspected as much. You have to check if the key exists. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is considered a good practice to check whether a key exists in a dictionary, before adding it. This is done with `Dictionary.Exist(key)` method.
- Adding key and value as variables is a good work around - `myVal = oCell2.Offset(, 2).Value & oCell2.Offset(, 3).Value`, improving the readability of the code.
- Declared like this `Dim Dic, Dic1 As Object, key As Variant, oCell, oCell2 As Range`, `Dic` and `oCell` are initially declared as `Variant`. Later they are assigned to the correct type.
- If cells in Excel are compared, it is a good idea to try to escape possible erorrs. Because two errors are never equal: `If (Not IsError(oCell.Value)) And (Not IsError(oCell2)) Then` and an error would be thrown:

---

```
Sub UpdateW2()
    Dim Dic As Object, Dic1 As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, oCell2 As Range, i&, i1&
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set w1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set w2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("B2:D" & i)
        If Not Dic.Exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 1).Value & oCell.Offset(, 2).Value
            i1 = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

            For Each oCell2 In w2.Range("B2:E" & i1)
                Dim myKey As String
                Dim myVal As String

                myKey = oCell2.Value
                myVal = oCell2.Offset(, 2).Value & oCell2.Offset(, 3).Value

                If Dic1.Exists(myKey) Then
                    Debug.Print "Key exists " & myKey
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Key added " & myKey
                    Dic1.Add myKey, myVal
                End If

                If (Not IsError(oCell.Value)) And (Not IsError(oCell2)) Then
                    If oCell = oCell2 Then
                        oCell.Offset(, 3).Value = oCell2.Offset(, 1).Value
                    End If
                Else
                    Debug.Print oCell.Address; " or "; oCell2.Address
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In your code i am getting only last value of the match but i want to match all 3 columns of both sheets and if all 3 are matching in both sheets then based on that i want to get the value of 4th column of that exact match. any suggestion how we can do that?

Comment: @LaxeshDave - the idea of the code is to give something workable that compiles and works. Concerning the "getting only last value of the match", then probably the business logic should be changed and reimplemented. E.g., on the line after the "`Debug.Print Key exists`", you may consider writing `Dic1(myKey) = Dic1(myKey) & myVal` or something similar, if this would suit your ideas.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. It works..!! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the key exists in Dic1 just as you did for Dic:

```vb
For Each oCell2 In w2.Range("B2:E" & i1)
    If Not Dic1.exists(oCell2.Value) Then
        Dic1.Add oCell2.Value, oCell2.Offset(, 2).Value & oCell2.Offset(, 3).Value
...
```

Also you need to properly format your code; you are lacking a `Next` for the second `For` loop.